# Is mongodb the right choice for building health related web application?

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure if stack-overflow is a right platform to ask the title question. I'm in dilemma as to which **front-end** and **back-end** stack should i consider for developing a **health related web application**?

I heartily appreciate any suggestions or recommendations. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have a look at your data, if it is relational, I would personally go for a SQL server such Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL or Postgres. If your data is non-relational you can go for something like Mongo.

Here is an image that explains how relational data and non-relational data work:
[image: SQL vs NonSQL]

I'm not saying that MongoDB is bad, it all depends on your data and how you would like to structure your data. Obviously when you're working with healthcare data such as patient data there are certain laws you need to adhere to, especially in the United States with HIPPA, but I am sure almost every country has one of those.

The implications might be that you need to encrypt any data stored in the database, and that's one of the benefits of a relational database as most of them have either [TDE (Transparent Data Encryption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017) or [Encryption at Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_at_rest#Encryption). Which means that your data is secured when in use and when not in use, respectively.

When it comes to the front-end you can look at Javascript frameworks such as Angular, Vue, React and then for your backend you can choose pretty much anything that you know well such as NodeJS or .NET Core or Go, pick your poison, each of them have their advantages and drawbacks so you will need to investigate your options before committing to one or the other.

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark my answer as correct if you feel so inclined :)

Comment: I do not know how to do so?

Comment: I think i have marked your answer as correct. In the meantime, can you please upvote my question, who knows someone might find it useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data structures. You can use MongoDB with dynamic schemas that eliminates the need for a predefined data structure. So you can use MongoDB when you have a dynamic dataset which is less relational. In the other hand, MongoDB is natively scalable. So you can store a large amount of data without much trouble.

Use a relational DB system when you have highly relational entities. SQL enables you to have complex transactions between entities with high reliability.

### MongoDB/NoSQL

- High write load
- Unstable Schemas
- Can handle big amount of data
- High availability

### SQL

- Data structure fits for tables and row
- Strict relationships among entities
- Complex queries
- Frequent updates in a large number of records

Comment: No problem. Feel free to upvote my answer if you think this is useful.